# android- java code doesnt recognize xml buttons

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

im trying to connect between my xml code to my java code on eclispe.
i have a button called bt1.
when im trying to do R.id.bt1- it doesnt recognize the bt1. meaning it did not get the xml code..
can you see wats wrong?

XML:`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/bt1"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    />
```

`

JAVA:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like anything is wrong. What are you trying to get the button to do exactly? Also, do you get an error whenever you run this?

Comment: will you please just do clean and build project.

Comment: If your layout file name is activity_main.xml, then a clean and re-build should solve the problem as suggested by Brijesh.

Comment: "it did not get the xml code". What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Please remove (`) after semicolon(;) from

Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);`

Comment: i dont think i had any (') in the end of the line. do you see any other reason for the dismatch?